# What is the advantage of C++ supporting native unsigned integers, while java does not?

Tags: c++, unsigned

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C%2B%2B C++ supports unsigned integers while java does not, what is the advantages of that?

Comment: You get an extra bit?

Comment: .. and as a bonus feature, now you have to worry about signedness :)

Comment: This question could be salvaged. E.g. "I found the following advantages `<list of reasons>` but they appear not so important. Is one of these really essential, or have I missed a very comeppling advantage?". Still, got to fill in that list first.

Answer (score 1):

A major difference is that C and C++ are used for low-level programming where bits are shifted and masked; an unsigned integer behaves naturally there.

And then for C++ there always is C compatibility. When C was conceived the larger value range may have been a reason too, when ints where 16 bit.

A minor point (for C) may be that for efficiency one wanted to support unsigned chars on architectures where those are the architecture default, and from there expand the concept of unsigned to all integer types in order to be orthogonal; although I find this argument weak.

Comment: There are plenty of valid use cases for unsigned ints - they tend to be mainly found in low level/embedded type applications, but there are also higher level examples such as 8 bit pixel values (0..255).

Comment: @PaulR I wrote that parallel to your comment. Probably indeed the main reason, and the major difference to Java.

Comment: Yes, I guess Java is not really pitched at low level code, or embedded applications or performance-critical stuff such as image processing.